# ASP.NET MVC jquery datepicker day could not be greater than month

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a problem while trying to use jquery datepicker in ASP.NET MVC. When I use jqueryui datepicker with jquery validation, I cannot save if the day is greater than month.(Ex `13/12/2015`). If the day was less than month (Ex `11/12/2015`), then my form saves the date. Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

This is an example of the code:

```
$("#Component_component_DateInService").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

---

```
<tr>
 <td>CF Expiry Date</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EquipmentStatutory.equipment_CfExpiryDate, new { @class = "mandatoryTextArea", @style = "width: 65px;", @required = "required" })</td>
</tr>
```

---

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic;
public partial class ASSET_EquipmentStatutory
{
    public string equipment_id { get; set; }
    public string equipment_RegNo { get; set; }
    public string equipment_CfNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> equipment_CfExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public string equipment_SSINo { get; set; }
    public string equipment_CfMachineDescEN { get; set; }
    public string equipment_CfMachineDescMY { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well maybe that's because it's trying to validate in mm/dd/yyyy format, you need to change to your actual culture (globalization), in web.config you could try to put this ` <globalization culture="en-US" />` after the `<system.web> open tag`. This works for me almost all the time

Comment: Thanks Jorge F. However, I manage to solve this problem by adding the below javascript for every page which has datepicker field: $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }
        var valid = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    });